# Locate two values "empty" and "incomplete", add the values that is one column before

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language, textjoin

I am creating a spreadsheet for homework completion. I want to search "empty space" and "incomplete" and add everything into one cell. everything is in one row.

I didn't do anything. I don't know how to start. I) would prefer a formula rather than a javascript.

For example:
John Doe has homework "empty" and "incomplete". I want to find these entries, go back one column where the actual homework is and concatenate it at the end of the row for example "p 34, p 35, p 37".

as a bonus, I would like maybe to add a due date for these homeworks. The date is located two rows up and 4 columns to the left from "empty" and "incomplete" cells.

For example: "p 34 due date was: July 27, 2019, p 35 due date was: July 24, 2019, p 37 due date was: July 21, 2019".

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XB8byleQCJg_zAPqkCIG5305SrD2AzwrvIseMhpkxXM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, QUERY({C8:D8;H8:I8;M8:N8;R8:S8;W8:X8;AB8:AC8}, 
 "select Col1 
  where Col1 is not null 
    and (Col2 = 'Incomplete' 
     or  Col2 = '')", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you. It is great. Now I need to dynamically build a query range. (this part , C8:D8;H8:I8;M8:N8;R8:S8;W8:X8;AB8:AC8). Depending on the date, the range will expand. How can I do it? For example, if the date is sept 12 then the range should automatically change to C8:D8;H8:I8;M8:N8;R8:S8;W8:X8;AB8:AC8,AG8:AH8